# Adding 1 digit to every single phone number in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, contactscontract

I want to create a function to edit every single number in my address book in android, however all the examples I found only edit 1 number of the contacts, so if the contact have more than 1 number they won't be edited.

For example:

Amy has this numbers:

```
093456432 - cellphone
2345678 - house
6789504 - work
34567832 - other
```

And the app will add 1 more digit for example "8" in the second position, so the change will result in something like:

```
0893456432 - cellphone
28345678 - house
68789504 - work
384567832 - other
```

And this needs to happen for every single contact in my address book.

Already tried with something like this (burnt a number to replace the original number just to test), but only edits the TYPE_HOME which is the phone number, and I wondered how could I do this, and if there is a global TYPE in which I can edit any number of the contact:

```
private void updateContact(String name, String phone)
{
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    String where =
        ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND "
            + String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE) + " = ? ";
    String[] params =
        new String[]
        {
            name,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
            String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME) };

    Cursor phoneCur = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, params, null);

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(where, params)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA, phone)
        .build());

    phoneCur.close();

    try
    {
        cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    }
    catch (RemoteException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (OperationApplicationException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "The number of have been updated " + name+ " to: " + phone,
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Regards.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'm morbidly intrigued as to why you would want to.

Comment: `Because we can` is all a nerd needs @kcoppock :)

Comment: New telecomunications regulation in my country, 1 more digit must be added to the phone numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere else in your program, you are reading the phone numbers. In that place, also read the type, and pass it as a parameter to `updateContact`.

Comment: This is the function i'm using to get the contacts, but don't know how to send it propertly to the update function since is a little complicate to managing all registries: http://pastebin.com/Rw3XUVRa